# Xamarin Community Toolkit input validation is true even when Entry is empty

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, xamarin-community-toolkit

This is my form with two entries for Mail and Phone and button Send

```xml
<StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="0"  Margin="0,5,0,5">
    <Label>
        <Label.FormattedText>
            <FormattedString>
                <Span  FontSize="16" Text="Phone" TextColor="#07987f"></Span>
                <Span  FontSize="16" Text=": " TextColor="#07987f"></Span>
            </FormattedString>
        </Label.FormattedText>
    </Label>
    <Entry x:Name="entryPhone" Placeholder="Phone" Text="{Binding Phone}">
        <Entry.Behaviors>
            <xct:TextValidationBehavior x:Name="phoneValidationRule" Flags="ValidateOnUnfocusing" RegexPattern="^07[0-9]{7}$"/>
        </Entry.Behaviors>
    </Entry>
</StackLayout>

<StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,5,0,5">
    <Label>
        <Label.FormattedText>
            <FormattedString>
                <Span  FontSize="16" Text="E-mail" TextColor="#07987f"></Span>
                <Span  FontSize="16" Text=": " TextColor="#07987f"></Span>
            </FormattedString>
        </Label.FormattedText>
    </Label>
    <Entry x:Name="entryEmail" Placeholder="Email" Text="{Binding Email}">
        <Entry.Behaviors>
            <xct:EmailValidationBehavior x:Name="emailValidationRule"  Flags="ValidateOnUnfocusing"/>
        </Entry.Behaviors>
    </Entry>
</StackLayout>

<Button Text="SEND" Clicked="ValidationFormForRegistraitonClicked" TextColor="#07987f"  BackgroundColor="#eeeeee"  Margin="0,10,0,10"></Button>
<StackLayout>
    <Label IsVisible="{Binding IsValidMail}" Text="ENTER VALID EMAIL"></Label>
    <Label  IsVisible="{Binding IsValidPhone}" Text="ENTER VALID PHONE"></Label>
</StackLayout>
```

And this is my validation function:

```
       private void ValidationFormForRegistraitonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

                if (!emailValidationRule.IsValid)
                    viewModel.IsValidMail = true;
                else
                    viewModel.IsValidMail = false;
                if (!phoneValidationRule.IsValid)
                    viewModel.IsValidPhone = true;
                else
                    viewModel.IsValidPhone = false;              
        }
```

I have problem when the Entry is empty that is Valid Statement and that is wrong. I have a simple requirement. If enter valid address and valid phone pass it. How to fix this?

Comment: EmailValidation and TextValidation have a MinimumLength property you could use that. Or use a custom regex or wrap it in a MultiValidation and combine some things

Comment: For phone you can change `Flags="ValidateOnAttaching"` it should work, for email @GeraldVersluis mentioned 3 ways to do it :)

Comment: @GeraldVersluis MinimumLenght=1 i add and still not working. When i don't enter antyhing return phone and Email validations are true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For phone you can just change when the behavior is applied by changing the `Flags` property value to `"ValidateOnAttaching"`:

```
<Entry x:Name="entryPhone" Placeholder="Phone" Text="{Binding Phone}">
      <Entry.Behaviors>
           <xct:TextValidationBehavior x:Name="phoneValidationRule" Flags="ValidateOnAttaching" RegexPattern="^07[0-9]{7}$"/>
      </Entry.Behaviors>
</Entry>
```

For phone you can use `MinimumLength` as GeraldVersluis mentioned in his comment

```
<Entry x:Name="entryEmail" Placeholder="Email" Text="{Binding Email}">
       <Entry.Behaviors>
             <xct:EmailValidationBehavior x:Name="emailValidationRule"  Flags="ValidateOnAttaching" MinimumLength="1"/>
        </Entry.Behaviors>
</Entry>
```

If this is not enough in some cases and you want more control on "when" to validate, you can call `ForceValidate()` method, for example inside your `ValidationFormForRegistraitonClicked()` event handler to force validation/re-evaluation, or whenever you think it is necessary.

```
private void ValidationFormForRegistraitonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            emailValidationRule.ForceValidate();
            phoneValidationRule.ForceValidate();

            if (!emailValidationRule.IsValid)
                 viewModel.IsValidMail = true;
            else
                viewModel.IsValidMail = false;
            if (!phoneValidationRule.IsValid)
                viewModel.IsValidPhone = true;
            else
                viewModel.IsValidPhone = false;              
}
```

Comment: first  thank you. Second, after testing all day i finishted learned this: u can use Flags with focus and  attacht for realtime visualization but in the end u must check with ```ForceValidate()``` because if u don't some of situations will get u wrong answer

Comment: Do the docs explain this at all? Or a sample that demonstrates `ValidateOnAttaching`, and has a comment? Once I saw your answer, I could google and find that flag in doc, but how did you learn this?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve For flags I didn't find an explicit doc with detailed explanation I guess it should be added to the [API docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.communitytoolkit.behaviors.validationflags?view=xamarin-community-toolkit), you can raise an issue regarding the docs on [this specific repo](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/xamarin-communitytoolkit/issues/50), you can also take a look at the source code and try to understand how each flag works or ask repo mainteners & community through GitHub discussion on the official repo.