# Xamarin Community Toolkit input validation is true when BindingContext is set

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

When the BindingContext is set, IsValid sets IsLastnameValid and IsFirstnameValid to true even if the required parameters are not correct. And I don't understand why.

**XMAL code**

```
<StackLayout>
    <Entry Placeholder="Lastname" Text="{Binding Lastname}">
        <Entry.Behaviors>
            <xct:TextValidationBehavior MinimumLength="3" MaximumLength="10"
                IsValid="{Binding IsLastnameValid}"/>
        </Entry.Behaviors>
    </Entry>

    <Entry Placeholder="Firstname" Text="{Binding Firstname}">
        <Entry.Behaviors>
            <xct:TextValidationBehavior MinimumLength="3" MaximumLength="10"
                IsValid="{Binding IsFirstnameValid}"/>
        </Entry.Behaviors>
    </Entry>

    <Button Text="Save" Clicked="OnSave">
        <Button.IsEnabled>
            <MultiBinding  Converter="{StaticResource BooleanAndConverter}">
                <Binding Path="IsLastnameValid"/>
                <Binding Path="IsFirstnameValid"/>
            </MultiBinding>
        </Button.IsEnabled>
    </Button>
</StackLayout>
```

**CS Code**

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    private UserViewModel _userViewModel;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _userViewModel = new UserViewModel(false, false);
        BindingContext = _userViewModel;
    }

    private void OnSave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("[User View Model Firstname] : " + _userViewModel.Firstname + "  " + _userViewModel.IsFirstnameValid);
        Console.WriteLine("[User View Model Lastname] : " + _userViewModel.Lastname + "  " + _userViewModel.IsLastnameValid);
    }
}
```

**ViewModel Code**
*I'm using the Nuget Package PropertyChanged.Fody*

```
[AddINotifyPropertyChangedInterface]
public class UserViewModel
{
    public UserViewModel(bool isLastnameValid, bool isFirstnameValid)
    {
        IsLastnameValid = isLastnameValid;
        IsFirstnameValid = isFirstnameValid;
    }

    public string Lastname { get; set; }
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public bool IsLastnameValid { get; set; }
    public bool IsFirstnameValid { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks for your help :)

**Edited to show the converter code**

```
public class BooleanAndConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {

        if (values.Any(value => value == null))
        {
            return false;
        }

        var result = values.OfType<IConvertible>().All(System.Convert.ToBoolean);
        return result;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException("BooleanAndConverter is a OneWay converter.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Xamarin Community Toolkit input validation is true even when Entry is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66103186/xamarin-community-toolkit-input-validation-is-true-even-when-entry-is-empty). `<xct:TextValidationBehavior ... Flags="ValidateOnAttaching" ...>`

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I've already tried it, It's making no difference :( I also tried different flags no difference, or maybe I'm using them in the wrong way

Comment: Hmm. I copied your code into a test app of mine, tested it, and setting that flag does change the behavior, for me. (Though I did it without Fody - I'll test with that, in a short while.) Are you testing on Android or iOS? Simulator or a specific device model? You can [download ToolmakeSteve - TestXFBugs](https://github.com/ToolmakerSteve/TestXFBugs). In that, project `TestBugs`'s `App.xaml.cs` has line `MainPage = new TextValidationPage();` - uncomment that line, and comment out any other "MainPage = " lines. See if that works for you.

Comment: on Android phone directly, Hawaii pro 20 mate

Comment: If you run on Android emulator, does it happen there also?

Comment: Yes, same problem. If you want you can download my code [Link](https://github.com/jbdioli/MyValidationButtonXaml.git) to see if you can reproduce the problem too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240275/discussion-between-toolmakersteve-and-jbd).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code works in my test repo (see link in my comment above):

```
<Entry Placeholder="Lastname" Text="{Binding Lastname}">
    <Entry.Behaviors>
        <xct:TextValidationBehavior MinimumLength="3" MaximumLength="10"
         Flags="ValidateOnAttaching, ValidateOnValueChanging" IsValid="{Binding IsLastnameValid}"/>
    </Entry.Behaviors>
</Entry>
```

The only change from yours is the addition of attribute

```
Flags="ValidateOnAttaching, ValidateOnValueChanging"
```

Given that, pressing Save button results in debug output with "false" for `IsValid`.

---

**EDITTED**: If you set flags manually, then the default flags don't apply. So need to list all desired flags. I've changed the code snippet above.

See [ValidationFlags enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.communitytoolkit.behaviors.validationflags).

You might also want to include `, ValidateOnUnfocusing`. This checks again when user leaves that control (e.g. clicks on another control).

Comment: Yes, this solution works, but now the button is always disabled because the "converter" is never triggered.

Comment: Let me edit the post to show you the converter

Comment: I see what you mean - converter isn't called after the start. Fun fact (that I just learned) - see EDITTED.

Comment: Yes !!! You found it !! Thanks so much